# Azure Mobile App using existing database

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I'm at my first attempt in using Azure Mobile App, and I should connect it to an existing and already populated SQL Azure DB. As far as I understand, one must add to the tables the *Version*, *CreatedAt*, *UpdatedAt*, and *Deleted* columns, and most important there must be and *id* column set as identity.

The problem is that on some tables I already have an identity column (eg. *ItemID*), wich I cannot rename without breaking existing third party applications that connects to the data.

The question is: Is there any way to avoid using the identity *Id* field, maybe someway mapping the original identity?

[edit]
I've already looked at the samples on the web, like that:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuremobile/2014/05/22/tables-with-integer-keys-and-the-net-backend/

but there seems to exist some differences between *mobile service* and *mobile app*, and I'd really be happy if someone point me out to the right direction, maybe with an usable example

Comment: Good grief folks, why was this question voted down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some adaptations the sample worked!

Taking as starting point the tutorial here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2014/07/17/walkthrough-attaching-an-azure-sql-database-to-your-net-backend/

here's what I've done:

1. *Added to my table the ***ITableData*** mandatory fields:

   > [Version]        ROWVERSION         NOT NULL,
   >   [CreatedAt]      DATETIMEOFFSET (7) DEFAULT (sysutcdatetime()) NOT NULL,
   >   [UpdatedAt]      DATETIMEOFFSET (7) NULL,
   >   [Deleted]        BIT                DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL
2. Created the model with ***EF Code First From database***
3. Created the DTO class with only the data fields and inherited from EntityData
4. *Created the custom MappingDomaninManager like this:

   ```
   public class MSSEntityDomainManager<TData, TModel>
           : MappedEntityDomainManager<TData, TModel>
           where TData : class, ITableData, new()
           where TModel : class
   {
   private Expression<Func<TModel, object>> dbKeyProperty;

   public MSSEntityDomainManager(MssContext context, 
                                 HttpRequestMessage request, 
                                 Expression<Func<TModel, object>> dbKeyProperty):base(context, request)
   {
       this.dbKeyProperty = dbKeyProperty;
   }

   public override Task<bool> DeleteAsync(string id)
   {
       return this.DeleteItemAsync(ConvertId(id));
   }

   public override SingleResult<TData> Lookup(string id)
   {
       return this.LookupEntity(GeneratePredicate(id));
   }

   public override Task<TData> UpdateAsync(string id, Delta<TData> patch)
   {
       return await this.UpdateEntityAsync(patch, ConvertId(id));
   }

   private static Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> GeneratePredicate(string id)
   {
       var m = Mapper.FindTypeMapFor<TModel, TData>();
       var pmForId = m.GetExistingPropertyMapFor(new AutoMapper.Impl.PropertyAccessor(typeof(TData).GetProperty("Id")));
       var keyString = pmForId.CustomExpression;
       var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, bool>>(
           Expression.Equal(keyString.Body, Expression.Constant(id)),
           keyString.Parameters[0]);
       return predicate;
   }

   private object ConvertId(string id)
   {
       var m = Mapper.FindTypeMapFor<TData, TModel>();
       var keyPropertyAccessor = GetPropertyAccessor(this.dbKeyProperty);
       var pmForId = m.GetExistingPropertyMapFor(new AutoMapper.Impl.PropertyAccessor(keyPropertyAccessor));
       TData tmp = new TData() { Id = id };
       var convertedId = pmForId.CustomExpression.Compile().DynamicInvoke(tmp);
       return convertedId;
   }

   private PropertyInfo GetPropertyAccessor(Expression exp)
   {
       if (exp.NodeType == ExpressionType.Lambda)
       {
           var lambda = exp as LambdaExpression;
           return GetPropertyAccessor(lambda.Body);
       }
       else if (exp.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
       {
           var convert = exp as UnaryExpression;
           return GetPropertyAccessor(convert.Operand);
       }
       else if (exp.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
       {
           var propExp = exp as System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression;
           return propExp.Member as PropertyInfo;
       }
       else {
           throw new InvalidOperationException("Unexpected expression node type: " + exp.NodeType);
       }
   }
   }
   ```

   The differences with the original sample are the complete removal of the ***ApiServices*** reference from the constructor, and the addition of the ***AutoMapper.Impl*** namespace to PropertyAccessor, otherwise by default it will use the ***System.Web.Http.OData*** one.
5. *Created the SQL utility class exactly like the one in the example

   ```
   public static class MySqlFuncs
   {
       [DbFunction("SqlServer", "STR")]
       public static string StringConvert(long number)
       {
           return number.ToString();
       }
       [DbFunction("SqlServer", "LTRIM")]
       public static string LTRIM(string s)
       {
           return s == null ? null : s.TrimStart();
       }
       // Can only be used locally.
       public static long LongParse(string s)
       {
           long ret;
           long.TryParse(s, out ret);
           return ret;
       }
   }
   ```

   This one I've decided to put in a separate "utility" file
6. *Created the mapping in *Startup.MobileApp.cs* file, as the WebApiConfig.cs mentioned in the samples don't exist in the Mobile App. The Automapper initialize code is working as-is, and I've put it just after *HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();* in *ConfigureMobileApp* function. For reference:

   ```
   AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
           {
               // Mapping from database type to client type
               cfg.CreateMap<StuffToGet, StuffToGetDto>()
                   .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, map => map.MapFrom(src => MySqlFuncs.LTRIM(MySqlFuncs.StringConvert(src.ID))));
               // Mapping from client type to database type
               cfg.CreateMap<StuffToGetDto, StuffToGet>()
                   .ForMember(dst => dst.ID, map => map.MapFrom(src => MySqlFuncs.LongParse(src.Id)));

           });
   ```

Marked with the "*" are the points that are different from the original msdn post.
Hope someone found that helpful!