# Azure mobile app with existing sql backend

Tags: azure-sql-database, automapper, azure-mobile-services

I have been following these examples in a previous stack overflow example, I need to convert to an Integer id to an Azure mobile app, and need a MappingDomainManager class described by user Kiske1 in the post below.

[Azure Mobile App using existing database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36036455/azure-mobile-app-using-existing-database)

However, I have been unable to complete this as Automapper.impl.PropertyAccessor is “Type of namespace Impl does not exist…” I am using the latest Automapper dll v6.1.1.0.

Does anyone know where PropertyAccessor has been moved to/or replaced with? 
Also, both examples that were specified in this post are from 2014, does anyone know of a more up to date walkthrough and preferably an example project?

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know where PropertyAccessor has been moved to/or replaced with?

I searched at [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) project and found that `PropertyAccessor` has been removed. Also, I checked my mobile app project and the Automapper version is 3.3.1, the `PropertyAccessor` exists and the old [sample](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2014/07/17/walkthrough-attaching-an-azure-sql-database-to-your-net-backend/) could work. I assumed that you could try to downgrade the version of your Automapper to fix this issue.

> does anyone know of a more up to date walkthrough and preferably an example project?

For Automapper 6.1.1, the usage for `FindTypeMapFor` method and the parameter type for `GetExistingPropertyMapFor` method have changed, you could modify your code under `SimpleMappedEntityDomainManager` as follows:

```
var m = Mapper.FindTypeMapFor<TModel, TData>();
m.GetExistingPropertyMapFor(new PropertyAccessor(typeof(TData).GetProperty("Id")));
```

To

```
var m = Mapper.Configuration.FindTypeMapFor<TModel, TData>();
m.GetExistingPropertyMapFor(typeof(TData).GetProperty("Id"));
```

Moreover, you could refer to adrian hall's book about [The Domain Manager](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/domainmgr/).